# (Python) How to plot different lines for each distinct value of a column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm reading a csv file and it has 3 columns: one indicates a database table name, other indicates the size of that table and the last column is the log date. It looks something like the image below and below that is how I want my graph to look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'table_name': ['x_table', 'x_table', 'y_table', 'y_table', 'z_table', 'z_table'], 'size_mb': [3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6],
        'log_date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-05-22 08:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-23 08:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-22 08:00:00'),
                     pd.Timestamp('2020-05-23 08:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-22 08:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-23 08:00:00')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: example of what table looks like]

[image: how i want the graph]

How can I do this?

Comment: `df.pivot(index='log_date', columns='table_name', values='size_mb').plot()`

Comment: `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='log_date', y='size_mb', hue='table_name')`